# Linking NSMenu to ViewController - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, nsmenu

I am working on a Yosemite app in swift and have hit a road block.

I have multiple views working properly, and now I want to implement custom menu actions. To keep the answer simple, how would I achieve this example. I want to click a menu button and have it change text on the viewcontroller. I have tried setting up IBActions, but I'm not sure how to make the link to the viewcontroller from the AppDelegate. How do you connect the two?

I'm still figuring this stuff out, so any insight would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

*UPDATE. I tried making a object and linking it that way. No luck.

When you press "Test" it prints test, however it's in it's own class. I need to do something in my main ViewController class. How to I make that reference?

[image: NSMenu]

Comment: could you post a code of  AppDelegate?

Answer (score 5):

Getting `NSViewController` from `NSWindow` is an easy solution.
If your app has multiple windows, select appropriate one through `keyWindow` or `windows` of `NSApplication`.

```
@IBAction func pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let window = NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow {
        if let viewController = window.contentViewController as? YourViewController {
            // do stuff
            ...
        }
    }
}
```